# TYPO3 get usergroups with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am trying to get the usergroup titles which belong to the current fe_user.
I have this script as an example, but it returns me all the usergroups.

If I only implement the first 3 lines, the correct usergroup uid comes out. What should be changed?

```
    30 = TEXT
    30.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
    30.required = 1
    30.split {
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1 || 2
        1 {
            10 = CONTENT
            10.table = fe_groups
            10.select.pidInList = 25
            10.select.andWhere.current = 1
            10.select.andWhere.wrap = uid=|
            10.renderObj = TEXT
            10.renderObj.field = title
            10.renderObj.wrap = |,
        }
        2 < .1
        2.10.renderObj.wrap >
    }
```

Comment: Your TypoScript works as expected (for me). The first three lines will return a comma separated list of all frontend usergroups which were assigned to the current user. The following lines will use this list to output the titles of all these usergroups (limited to PID 25). While cObj `1` returns the titles comma separated, `2` renders them a second time without commas. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Like I said, I found this script as an example. But I just want the titles of the usergroups of the fe_user. And this example produces all usergroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it, the problem was andWhere, it should be where.

```
    30 = TEXT
    30 {
        data = TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
        required = 1
        split {
            token = ,
            cObjNum = 1

            1.10 = CONTENT
            1.10 {
                table = fe_groups
                select {
                    pidInList = {$pages.frontEndUsers}
                    where.current = 1
                    where.wrap = uid=|
                }
                renderObj = TEXT
                renderObj.field = title
                renderObj.wrap = |,
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i edit the Output from the last item, without comma , ? dont work: wrap = |, |*| |, |*| |